# Where definitions in public.xml are linking to?

Tags: android

Let me explain with example... Consider 'android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice'. It used to create multi-select lists. But the only definitions I found:

/platform/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml:

```
<public type="layout" name="simple_list_item_multiple_choice" id="0x01090010" />
```

/platform/frameworks/base/api/current.xml:

```
<field name="simple_list_item_multiple_choice"
 type="int"
 transient="false"
 volatile="false"
 value="17367056"
 static="true"
 final="true"
 deprecated="not deprecated"
 visibility="public"
>
```

But where is actual layout defined? When multi-select list created I see checkbox, where it comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/$YOUR_PLATFORM/data/res/layout/simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml`, where `$ANDROID_HOME` is wherever you installed your SDK and `$YOUR_PLATFORM` is whatever platform version you are interested in (e.g., `android-2.1`).

For example, for Android 2.1, the layout is:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
/>
```